# Parsing received GCM message into push notification

Tags: android

I'm sending GCM messages from my server to my application.

the notification works with sample data, but when I'm trying to use the received message information from my server, I get empty values.

**The is exmplae for a message I get from my server: (received as msg at showNotification())**

```
Received: {
"subtitle": "text",
"sound": "1",
"message": "bla bla",
etc..
```

This is how I tried to handle it (look for **showNotification()**):

```
public class GcmService extends GcmListenerService {
    String title;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        Set<String> keys = data.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            try {
                jsonObject.put(key, data.get(key));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            sendNotification("Received: " + jsonObject.toString(5));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {
        sendNotification("Deleted messages on server");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageSent(String msgId) {
        sendNotification("Upstream message sent. Id=" + msgId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSendError(String msgId, String error) {
        sendNotification("Upstream message send error. Id=" + msgId + ", error" + error);
    }

    private void sendNotification(final String msg) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainActivity.mTextView.setText(msg);

                //JSON Parsing
                try {
                    JSONObject thePush = new JSONObject(msg);
                    JSONArray pushData;
                    pushData = thePush.optJSONArray("Received");
                    thePush = pushData.optJSONObject(0);
                    if (thePush != null) {
                        //Initalize data from my JSON
                        title = thePush.optString("title");
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.beer)
                                .setContentTitle(title)
                                .setContentText("Hello World!");
                // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                                0,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                        );
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
                mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
            }
        });
    }


}
```

When I Receive GCM message from the below code, I get a message with no title.
the body works since the value is not from my json, for testing.

What's the problem with the way I received the json?

Comment: can you add `msg` that you are getting in  `sendNotification` method in your question ?

Comment: This is it: `Received: {
"subtitle": "text",
"sound": "1",
"message": "bla bla",
etc..` (The message I posted)

Comment: May be yours is not a valid json, post your json here at http://jsonlint.com/ and check if it is valid or not

Comment: I think you are right, It returns error, then how do I handle this received array?

Comment: you will need to convert it as a valid json format from server and then send it to app

Comment: or else try like this in your `onMessageReceived()` method -> `String title = data.getString("subtitle","defaultvalue");` and see what you are getting in `title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data you are receiving is already in `json` format so you can do something like below to get `value` from the corresponding `key`

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String subtitle = data.getString("subtitle","defValue");
    String sound = data.getString("sound","defValue");
    String message = data.getString("message","defValue");
    //..... fetch other values similarly 

    Log.d("Data ->",subtitle+"-"+sound+"-"+message);
}
```